# Advantages of XML Serialization (OOP) over LINQ to XML?

Tags: vb.net, oop, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I am importing xml data from one API and posting xml data to another.

My first attempt utilised LINQ's embedded values to transform the relevant values as follows:

```
Dim DetailXML = From product In ProductXML _
  Select <detail>
          <detail.stockcode><%= product.<sku>.Value %></detail.stockcode>
          <detail.stockqty><%= product.<quantity>.Value %></detail.stockqty>
          <detail.orderqty><%= product.<quantity>.Value %></detail.orderqty>
          <detail.gross><%= product.<total_inc_tax>.Value %></detail.gross>
          <detail.taxcode><%= DetailTaxCode %></detail.taxcode>
         </detail>
```

This is fairly neat, it's easy to follow and it only required about 200 lines of code to end up with something that works perfectly well.

Following various comments on this site regarding 'best practice', I have re=developed this as an object-orientated solution, using xml serialization.

I now have classes/objects for all the relevant tables/fields, complete with xml attributes for flawless serialization.

This has been a major undertaking and the end result is about 10 times more code for the the entire project, but not significantly less code for the actual import/export loops.

My question is **why did I bother?**  **What are the practical advantages (if any) of the object-orientated approach in this instance?**

This is not an idle question:  Data importation/transformation/export to/from APIs are the bread and butter of the IT generalist and this is by no means a unique project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could argue that creating a few objects is **cleaner, less verbose and less error-prone** than creating the XML yourself using XML literals. Also, **C#** people don't have XML literals (I envy you).

`XmlSerializer` is, in my opinion, best-used if you need **deserialization** as well. Parsing XML using XLINQ results in not exactly the best kind of code quality.

`XmlSerializer` is also useful if you need **both saving and loading**. YOu can use it very nicely as a configuration store for example.

You can also **generate** classes from an XML schema. If one is available this is usually the best option.

Comment: This are good points, but in this case I think tat cost/benefit, rather than pure technical arguments will win the day.  effective OOP requires expertise, planning and skill, whereas XML manipulation via linq (or simple string manipulation) is quick and concise, albeit inelegant.  A good practice to have learned about, however.  Thank you.

Comment: I speak purely from a productivity standpoint here. I only design for clarity as a means to save time and reduce cost. Elegance often is a means to save cost. It is a heuristic.